Can the given matrices be considered as the generators of $sl(2)$ Lie algebra?
If $\{X,Y,H\}$ are generators of $sl(2)$ Lie algebra they obey the following commutation relations
$$  [X,Y]=-2H , \quad   [X,H]=-X , \quad [Y,H]=Y.     \hspace{40pt}    (1)$$
Question.

Can I claim that the following matrices, that obey the commutation relations $(1)$, are $5$-dimensional matrix representations of $sl(2)$ Lie algebra? In general, can we consider any matrices that satisfy $(1)$ as $sl(2)$ generators?

$$   X=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} ,\quad Y=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} ,\quad H=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix} .$$
P.S. I would appreciate it if someone could kindly introduce me references so that I can find examples of matrix representations of $sl(2)$ Lie algebra.

Yes, any time you've found three $n \times n$ matrices obeying those commutation relations you've found an $n$-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. This specific one looks like the unique $5$-dimensional irreducible representation. In general there's a unique $n$-dimensional irreducible representation for every $n$.

You are presenting the 5-dimensional representation of the angular momentum Lie-algebra of  $SU(2)$ , not $ sl(2, (\mathbb Q,\mathbb R, \mathbb C?)),$
in Hilbert space $\mathcal  H(S_2) $ as a factor in $\mathcal  H(\mathbb R^3) $  of the representation of the scalar Heisenberg algebra.
One identifies the ladder operators
$$(X,Y) \ =  \ L_1\pm \ i \ L_2 \  \ 
= -i \left(y \partial_z -  z \partial_y\right) 
\pm  \left( z \partial_x - x \partial_z \right)  \quad  H=L_3 =-i (x \partial_y - y \partial x ) = -i \ \partial_\phi $$ in the subspace of Spherical Harmonics $$Y_{2,m}(\theta,\phi), m=-2,\dots,2 $$ that represent the space of homogenous monomials of degree 5 in $x,y,z$, invariant under the rotation group $SO(3)$ in euclidean $\mathbb R^3.$
Its evident, that the series of spaces of ordered homogenous monomials in $n$ variables of  degree $m$ in euclidean $\mathbb R^n$ induce a series of irreducible representations of $SO(n)$ of hyperspherical functions on the sphere $S^{n-1}$ by the very fact, that rotations don't change the total exponent of monomials.
We know that the euclidean square of angular momentum operator  in spherical coordinates   is the Laplacian  $$\Delta_{S^2 }\ = \ \frac{1}{\sin \theta} \partial_\theta \sin \theta \partial_\theta + \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta} {\partial_\phi}^2$$
In the 5-d representation subspace we identify
$$\vec L^2 \ = \left(H^2 -\frac{1}{2} (X.Y +Y.X)\right)  (1,1,1,1,1)=(6,6,6,6,6) =2 \times(2+1) \ (1,1,1,1,1) $$
$$H ( 1,1,1,1,1 )=(2,1,0,-1,-2)$$
the eigenvalue equations for the spherical harmonics
$$\Delta_{S^2} Y_{lm} = l(l+1) Y_{l,m}, \quad L_z \ Y_{lm} \ = \ m \ Y_{l,m} $$
Observe, that products  of elements of the abstract Lie algebra are undefined. It needs a linear representation and the analysis of its Casimir operator set to get representation dependent aspects of the free algebra.
The total representation space of SU(2) is an infinite direct product of integer and half odd integer eigenvalues of the diagonal matrix $H$, splitting into a sum of the integer and half odd integer series (superselection rule, Pauli principle, spin and statistics).
The complete series is conventionally described by the representation  theory of the total angualar momentum operators $$J = L + \frac{1}{2} \sigma$$.
The integer series can be described by the dimension $l$ of your ladder operators $X,Y$ and eigenvalue of the diagonal $H$ operator setting the spin oprator $\sigma =0 $ by or an even sum of spin $(2s)\frac{1}{2}$.
The half odd integer series is doubling each state, because physically speaking the total angular momentum $J_z=L_z \pm\frac{1}{2} $ can be represented by $j_z= m+ \frac{1}{2} | (m+1)- \frac{1}{2}$ that despite the same value of the $J,J_z$ react differently wrt. to a weak external magnetic field.
Much more complex is $sl(2,\mathbb C)$, that is the building block of representations of the identity component of the Lorentz group and has 3 more elements representing the three generators of hyperbolic rotations in time and one space coordinate, the boost operators.
The three boost operators, images of $-i (x \partial_t + t \partial_x) $ in $sl(2,\mathbb C)$  have the same Lie-algebra as the rotation algebra, but the mixed Lie-products of the six generators map into the boost subgroups.
